# Magento: Can you set it so all Websites share the same order increment id sequence?

Tags: magento

Does anyone know if it is possible to make it so all websites or stores share the same order increment ID. Basically we are working with an ERP system that is allowing us to submit our Invoice number to be the actual order number in the system, the thing is though, they only need one number sequence not a different one for each store like how Magento does by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just found this out and it is pleasantly easy. You could put the following in an upgrade script...

```
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')
    ->loadByCode('order')
    ->setIncrementPerStore(false)
    ->save();
```

<sub>**P.S.** I've been receiving requests to make an extension of this but one already exists: [Custom Order Number Pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1419/custom-order-number-pro). It's commercial but it has a decent sounding list of features.</sub>

Comment: Thanks clock, I will try that out, I don't understand why that wouldn't be a configuration change or why no one else has really posted anything about it anywhere :)

Comment: It makes sense to release this as an extension, I can do it easily. Out of curiosity, do the combined increments start with 0?

Comment: Yes it does, I looked in the code and it is looking to see if the is true and if not it puts the admin store number in front

Answer (score 0):

You can change it directly in the database. See table `eav_entity_type` and column `increment_per_store` (change this to 0).
Another numbering information is stored in `eav_entity_store`

Answer (score 0):

> You can change it directly in the database. See table eav_entity_type and column increment_per_store (change this to 0).
>   Another numbering information is stored in eav_entity_store

Unfortunately this doesn't work if you use Sisow and iDeal payments. The orders aren't sent to client nor admin. I had to undo the changes. Now it's back to working order but still no working solution for continuous order numbers in multi-store config.

Br,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can change it directly in the database. See table sales_sequence_meta => column sequence_table and change reference of 'order' in 'entity_type' to same table like sequence_order_0.

Ex:        Default Table
meta_id entity_type store_id sequence_table

5        order         1     sequence_order_1

6        order         2     sequence_order_2

7        order         3     sequence_order_3

8        order         4     sequence_order_4

Change To

5        order         1     sequence_order_0

6        order         2     sequence_order_0

7        order         3     sequence_order_0

8        order         4     sequence_order_0

This may help you.