# Multiple Websites share the same order increment id sequence?

Tags: magento

I noticed this question as asked before but i am not sure how to implement the answer. This is the link.

[Magento: Can you set it so all Websites share the same order increment id sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205161/magento-can-you-set-it-so-all-websites-share-the-same-order-increment-id-sequenc)

Can you tell me which file to add this to and what line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add a new module or edit one that you have existing and add this to your config.xml, obviously change to match your setup.

```
<resources>
<module_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>Package_Module</module>
        <class>Package_Module_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
    </setup>
    <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
</module_setup>
</resources>
```

You will want to add that class to be located app/code/local/Package/Module/Model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup.php

Then you create a sql folder under
app/code/local/Package/Module/

and then create a folder called module_setup under the sql folder. so the path should look like this
app/code/local/Package/Module/sql/module_setup

Inside of this folder you will put your install or upgrade script based on the version number of your module such as mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

This is version number can be located in your config.xml such as the following

```
<modules>
<Package_Module>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</Package_Module>
</modules>
```

You should then have a file located with the following structure
app/code/local/Package/Module/sql/module_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

Inside that file you can setup the file with the following

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
   your code here
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

You can then open your browser and hit any url on your site and it should update if not you can keep testing by deleting the recorder for module_setup under the core_resources table.

Comment: I think you could also do this without creating the whole sql setup, I am not sure off the top of my head, maybe someone will post that.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it directly in the database. See table sales_sequence_meta => column sequence_table and change reference of 'order' in 'entity_type' to same table like sequence_order_0.

Ex: Default Table
meta_id entity_type store_id sequence_table

5 order 1 sequence_order_1

6 order 2 sequence_order_2

7 order 3 sequence_order_3

8 order 4 sequence_order_4

Change To

5 order 1 sequence_order_0

6 order 2 sequence_order_0

7 order 3 sequence_order_0

8 order 4 sequence_order_0

This may help you.